# How to find the correct GUID in DLL to match its Pdb?

Tags: dll, pdb

I have been searching online and found the answer from @chentiangemalc

```
You can also look for structure starting with signature RSDS (0x53445352),   
is followed by a GUID (16 bytes), 
a counter (4 bytes) and then the PDB pathname.
```

This works for most cases.

Except for this one:

I have a dll [System.Collections.dll](https://github.com/huangmin-ms/DotNetFundamentals/blob/main/System.Collections.dll) and imported to dotpeek. The GUID is `016f38124dcc4f82a73b12c7baf82e3e` which doesn't work.

https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/System.Collections.pdb/016f38124dcc4f82a73b12c7baf82e3eFFFFFFFF/System.Collections.pdb

[dotpeek screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5paL3.png)

The dotpeek loaded the pdb from blew url:

Downloader: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/system.collections.pdb/552b6fdf67184d5ab8ee8c8887f505b2FFFFFFFF/system.collections.pdb -> ok, 41.9 KB

Not sure where `552b6fdf67184d5ab8ee8c8887f505b2FFFFFFFF` comes from?

This is the result from `dumpbin`:

Debug Directories

```
    Time Type        Size      RVA  Pointer
-------- ------- -------- -------- --------
C8A1BD67 cv            66 00009F38     8138    Format: RSDS, {016F3812-4DCC-4F82-A73B-12C7BAF82E3E}, 1, /_/artifacts/obj/System.Collections/ref/net6.0-Release/System.Collections.pdb
00000000 pdbhash       27 00009F9E     819E    SHA256: 12 38 6F 01 CC 4D 82 5F 67 3B 12 C7 BA F8 2E 3E 67 BD A1 48 68 C7 9C 0F 1A 0E 5C 92 0D E7 E9 EC
00000000 repro          0 00000000        0
```